# read.csv2.ffdf is importing a numeric (float) variable as factor

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a couple weeks working with the ff package and it has been working great so far,
but today I realized that a variable that should be numeric is being readed as a factor.
The data has about 900k rows and 800 col, so it's not easy to control that every column gets the class that it should...

```
matff <- read.csv2.ffdf(file = name,encoding = "UTF-8",next.rows=150000,colClasses=NA)
```

I would like to know why may this be happening and an idea on how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: If possible, do a table() in one of the variables with problem and check if there isn't any error message (from excel ou another data provider)... and you are sure you need use read.csv2() (decimal pointo equal , and separator ;) instead read.csv (decimal point equal to . and separator ,)?

Comment: I already checked the levels() and the table() for the problem variable and I dont see any problem... I am using csv2 because the data (wich comes from sql server) is separated by ";" and decimals are marqued with "."

Comment: That's the problem, csv2 set decimal to ','... try `read.table()` with parameters `sep=';'` and `dec='.'`

Comment: well, I was wrong... the problem comes from the fact that the variables are come both with "." and "," as decimal separator....  and csv2 was taking with "." ones as a factor...

Comment: Your data has only numbers or the are any text (specifically any text with '.' on it)... i'm thinking in read all as text, replace all ',' for '.' and them transform all in numeric

Comment: there are character variables, mixed types like emails that contain "." and numeric variables that for some reason have "." and ","

Answer (score 1):

Your data has some columns which are clearly texts and not numeric data as you expect it.

You can use the transFUN argument to read.csv2.ffdf to solve your decimal problem. As in

```
transFUN=function(x){
  x$mycolumn <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", as.character(x$mycolumn)))
  x
}
```

Or use the appropriate read.table arguments.

Comment: The OP mentioned that the column is imported as `factor` so just a `as.numeric` won't do

Comment: my idea is to keep reading the , separated as numbers and change somehow the . ones... it would be nice to use the stringsAsCharacter = True or something like that. I tried with the transFUN like this `matff <- read.table.ffdf(file = name,FUN = "read.csv",next.rows=150000,colClasses=NA, sep=";",dec=".",transFUN=function(x){
  x$mycolumn <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", as.character(x$mycolumn)))
  x
})` but I get an error when there is nothing to change Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "mycolumn", value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 150000

Comment: Don't forget to replace 'mycolumn' with the column name where your column is read in as a factor while you wanted it as a numeric.

Comment: the problem is I don't know the names off all columns with this problem. I think i will convert all factor col to char and then loop

Answer (score 1):

Now it should work:

```
# matff <- data.frame(Col=c('a','b','c'),Mix1=c('a','1.2','c'),Mix2=c(1.1,2.1,3),Num1=c('1.2','2.3','3.4'),Num2=c('1,2','2,3','3,4')) # Data example

func <- function(x) {
 if (class(x) != 'numeric') {
  x <- levels(x)[x]
  if (length(grep('[a-zA-Z]',x,invert=T)) == length(x)) { x <- as.real(gsub(',','\\.',x)) }
  else { x <- factor(x) }
 }
 x
}

for (i in 1:ncol(matff)) {
 matff[,i] <- func(matff[,i])
}
```

Comment: `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` cant be used in the read.csv2.ffdf function I though to do that too but got this `Error in read.table.ffdf(file = name, FUN = "read.csv", encoding = "UTF-8",  : 
  unkown arguments: stringsAsCharacter`

Comment: Try with `matff <- read.csv2.ffdf(file = name,encoding = "UTF-8",next.rows=150000,colClasses=NA)`

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but given the size of the data and that I'm working with an ffdf i rather do something on the import rather than iterate through all the matrix